Cannot import go-gl library - "build constraints exclude all Go files"
I'm very new to golang, sorry if this is obvious. I've followed the steps from the project Github, and here is my exact procedure (with error):
$ go mod init mydomain.com/test
$ go mod tidy
$ go get -u github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.6-core/gl
$ go run .
package evlis.org/nemo
        imports github.com/go-gl/gl: build constraints exclude all Go files in C:\Users\myname\go\pkg\mod\github.com\go-gl\gl@v0.0.0-20231021071112-07e5d0ea2e71

Why won't it find the go-gl package??
Here's the go.mod file:
module evlis.org/nemo

go 1.22.4

require github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw v0.0.0-20240506104042-037f3cc74f2a
require github.com/go-gl/gl v0.0.0-20231021071112-07e5d0ea2e71

And here's my full main.go:
package main

import (
    "log"
    "runtime"

    "github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.6-core/gl"
    "github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw"
)

const (
    width  = 500
    height = 500
)

func main() {
    runtime.LockOSThread()

    window := initGlfw()
    defer glfw.Terminate()

    program := initOpenGL()

    for !window.ShouldClose() {
        draw(window, program)
    }
}

// initGlfw initializes glfw and returns a Window to use.
func initGlfw() *glfw.Window {
    if err := glfw.Init(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.Resizable, glfw.False)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.ContextVersionMajor, 4) // OR 2
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.ContextVersionMinor, 1)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.OpenGLProfile, glfw.OpenGLCoreProfile)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.OpenGLForwardCompatible, glfw.True)

    window, err := glfw.CreateWindow(width, height, "Conway's Game of Life", nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    window.MakeContextCurrent()

    return window
}

// initOpenGL initializes OpenGL and returns an intiialized program.
func initOpenGL() uint32 {
    if err := gl.Init(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    version := gl.GoStr(gl.GetString(gl.VERSION))
    log.Println("OpenGL version", version)

    prog := gl.CreateProgram()
    gl.LinkProgram(prog)
    return prog
}

func draw(window *glfw.Window, program uint32) {
    gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    gl.UseProgram(program)

    glfw.PollEvents()
    window.SwapBuffers()
}

I've searched online and the specific repo for similar issues, closest I found was this, however go clean -modcache does not help in my case...

It's not that it can't find the package; rather, it can't build the module with the existing build constrants. What platform are you on? Are there platform limitations on the module you're trying to import?

Is there a way to view what those build constraints are? I'm on Windows 10, the package states Windows is supported?

There is only one file in github.com/go-gl/gl (generate.go; which generates other code,and is not intended to be imported so uses a build tag to prevent that). So you definitly want another package i.e. github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.6-core/gl (suggest you focus your question on that import). See this issue for one potential issue/solution.

Many thanks to @Brits for pointing me in the right direction.
The issue was not having the gcc compiler on my system. To fix, I downloaded GCC 14.1.0 Win64 - without LLVM/Clang/LLD/LLDB, added the extracted mingw64\bin to my user path environmental variable, and re-ran the following go commands:
$ go env -w "CGO_ENABLED=1"
$ go run .

Success.
